# Cracking WPA wireless network encryption

Tags: wireless, encryption, password

My teacher wont tell me the password of the wifi so I am wondering if there is a tool to know the security password of wifi.
I can see the name of network in the network manager but when I click on it, it asks me WPA and WPA2 Personal security.....

Comment: We could tell you, and there are most certainly (google) ways to do it, but I am pretty sure it would be illegal.

Comment: I don't think that this question is related to Ubuntu, besides I don't think it's a good idea to ask such a question here.

Answer (score 3):

You will find that WPA and WPA2 encryption, when used alongside a strong password, is not easy to crack, whichever operating system you use. If it was WEP you would have had a chance though, because that is a much weaker form of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no, there are no tools that will crack WPA and WPA2 encryption. If you see any on Google they are lying.

Besides if you get caught you cold risk being denied graduation or qualifications. Don't do it.

Comment: WTF, you scared me to death man. Someone close the question or I would jump off my window (I don't mean that window).